# Death Before Dishonor, Honor Before Death

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Could you have misheard me? I am not of darkness.
> Have I answered your plea? I'm known for my starkness.
>
> I am the hero's hero. I fight monsters and demons.
> Valor have I. Fear, zero. Courage, I fight against reason.
>
> A damsel in distress, I'll rescue and save,
> Listen all who oppress, I will be your grave.
>
> Righteous and virtuous, hear my great call!
> Ye who try to hurt us, your blade will fall!

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you a

> Knight

Could you have misheard me? I am not of darkness.
Have I answered your plea? I'm known for my starkness.

> The dark knight(and night and knight are homophones) and knights can save you.

I am the hero's hero. I fight monsters and demons.
Valor have I. Fear, zero. Courage, I fight against reason.

> They save kings and other heroes and they are brave.

A damsel in distress, I'll rescue and save,
Listen all who oppress, I will be your grave.

> They save Princesses and other damsels in distress and they save regular town people.

Righteous and virtuous, hear my great call!
Ye who try to hurt us, your blade will fall!

> They have swords.

The title and hidden clue,

> The title talks about what a knights believes and the first letter of each sentence spells CHIVALRY which is what a knight has.

Comment: That is correct, though I admit the first line is different than I intended. It has to do about hearing something similar, hence misheard.

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean I will add that in! Thanks for the puzzle